# Action on group cohomology

Tags: group-theory, homological-algebra, group-actions, group-cohomology

Let $A$ be an abelian group with an action of $S_3$. Then one has the spectral sequence $H^i (\mathbb{Z}/2, H^j (\mathbb{Z}/3, A))$ converging to $H^{i+j} (S_3, A)$. I want to understand the action of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ on $H^1 (\mathbb{Z}/3, A)$. My question is the following: one can identify $H^1(\mathbb{Z}/3, A)$ with the group $Hom_{tw} (\mathbb{Z}/3, A)$ of twisted homomorphisms. Note that $\mathbb{Z}/2$ acts on both sides of this $Hom$ group and so it acts in the whole $Hom$ group. Is this the correct action? What bothers me is that this identification comes from the standard $\mathbb{Z} [\mathbb{Z}/3]$- resolution of the trivial module $\mathbb{Z}$ and this resolution is not $\mathbb{Z}/2$-equivariant. Thus, a priori it is not clear that this is "the correct" action.

Comment: Indeed, a $\mathbb{Z[Z/3Z]}$-resolution might not be $\mathbb{Z/2Z}$-equivariant. However, there are two ways you can see that there is indeed an action : either by functoriality, that is a map $f:M\to N$ induces $H^1(\mathbb{Z/3Z},M)\to H^1(\mathbb{Z/3Z},N)$, apply this to the map induced by a transposition : $A\to A$, or  by constructing a resolution which indeed have an action $S_3$ (say use the standard $\mathbb{Z}[S_3]$-resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ which will be a free $\mathbb{Z[Z/3Z]}$ resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: @Roland I don't think your first description of the action is correct. It would imply that the action is trivial on $H^1(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z,M)$ if the action on $M$ is trivial. However for $M=\Bbb Z/\Bbb 3\Bbb Z$ with the trivial $S_3$-action, we get that $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ acts on $H^1(\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z,M)=\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ via inversion (I think).

Comment: If you want to argue via functoriality, you need to work with the category of compatible pairs. This category has objects $(G,M)$, where $G$ is a group and $M$ is a $G$-module. A morphism $(G,M) \to (H,N)$ is a pair $(\varphi,f)$, where $\varphi:G \to H$ is a group homomoprhism and $f:\varphi^*N \to M$ is a $G$-module homomorphism. Group cohomology is a functor on this category. If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $M$ is a $G$-module, then we have for each $g \in G$ the compatible pair given by $(h \mapsto g^{-1}hg, m \mapsto gm)$, this induces the conjugation action of $G/H$  on $H^n(H,M)$

Comment: @LukasHeger Yes you are right, it can't be what I wrote because the map induced by a transposition $A\to A$ isn't $\mathbb{Z/3Z}$-equivariant. Your description of functoriality is the good one.